# Why do i get this error on my webpage using xampp?

Tags: php

Warning:     mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1049): Unknown database

I tried to cross_check the names correctness and look for other sources of solutions but nothing worked out as i wished.

Comment: unknown database means that database name you've passed in mysqli_connect is unknown for mysql, ie - such database does not exist

Comment: Thanks... @Lashane

Answer (score 0):

The database you tried to use does not exist in the RDBMS you tried to reach. You might have missed running an import script or you might have mistyped the database name. Solution: make sure that the database you need exists and is referenced at the right connection using the right name.

Comment: Thanks all...I made it out! Remain blessed!

Comment: @Rezzy you are welcome. If this answer helped you solve your problem, then you might want to accept it as the correct answer.